# UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, tags, uitapgesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am quite new to Swift and I am fascinated to the potential of distinguish these two gesture for a button.

I am writing my first app in xCode and I am near to conclude that. As a last step I want to implement two different actions for a button depending on a long press or a tap.

I have constructed the app as follows. I have several buttons connected to one IBAction and distinguished them using tags.

coming to the tag of the one of the two buttons on which I need the long press action I don't know how to continue.

Do you have some suggestion?
Thank you so much

```
func longTap() {
            if (resultDisplay.text != ""){
                storedVariableA = String(result)
                eraseAll()
            }
        }
        else if (sender.tag == 20) {
                    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longTap(_:)))
                    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2 
                    sender.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)



                }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried the following. By pressing the button (by an if else construction), I check the tag of the button. In the corresponding if else statement I tried to distinguish the two cases without success.

Comment: `func longTap()` have to be declared out of `else if ` statement,not inside `if.. else`, it will be outside the `@IBAction` method

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I actually wrote the function outside the whole @IBAction. Sorry for the mistake of writing it wrongly. But it does not work anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in your `@IBAction` for the tag you given in storyboard or programmatically, Please check the below code.

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.tag == 22 { // check for your desired tag instead of "22"
        // add longpress gesture. on sender // sender represents your button.
        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPressGesture(_:)))
        longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2 // mention minimum press duration you want user to press.
        sender.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It does not seems to work.. I show you what I wrote in my question

Comment: What is your desired output ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: If I perform a long press on this button I want to store something, while if I just tap it I want to call the stored data.

Comment: Could you please help me?

Comment: @sky90 sure, how can I help you ?

Comment: oh... thank you for coming back! I still have the same problem. I followed your advices but is still not working. I posted what I've done in my question, could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your  `longTap()` func is wrong. In `longTap()` function you should define what ever you want to perform on longpress gesture. not to initialize gesture itself in that.

so your `longTap()` should look like below.

`func longTap() {
        // write what ever you want to perform on longpress gesture..
}`

Comment: thanks for your comment. actually I did not do that. I defined the function longTap in my viwecontroller and then in a @IBAction I took your tip by writing the longTap function instead but I get the following error:
"value of type ViewController has no member longTap"...